# Unable to download packages on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ros, package, raspberrypi, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm going through the tutorials and am unable to download the fuerte version of rqt to continue. Apparently the packages aren't showing up in the list. I initially installed ROS following these instructions:

```
www.ros.org/wiki/ROSberryPi/Setting%20up%20ROS%20on%20RaspberryPi
```

While going through the tutorial I went to install the applications like so:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/scripts $ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-qt-gui-core ros-fuerte-rqt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-qt-gui-core
E: Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-rqt
```

Are there any specific sources I need to have enabled to get these packages? Currently I just have the four defaults (I don't have enough karma yet to post the actual source urls, hopefully these are sufficient):

```
mirrordirector.raspbian.org
us.debian.org
packages.ros.org/ubuntu precise
archive.raspberrypi.org/debian wheezy
```

Thus far I haven't been able to locate the packages. I tried pulling the packages for a full fuerte desktop install into a VM, and that gave me all sorts of dependency issues. So I figure the ubuntu repos are out for this case.

Does anyone know how I can get this tool? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64993/unable-to-download-packages-on-raspberry-pi/) by [AlphaSierra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4924/alphasierra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 124 on 2013-06-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-06-12**:
Though not relevant to the question itself, I think adding sharp/pound at the beginning of the tag is only for when you search by tag according to help http://answers.ros.org/help/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As Marco said, the information should probably be put together in one place for more clarity.

That being said, and to answer your question, the tutorial that you have followed does not mention a package repository for ROS binaries. This means you will not be able to `apt-get install ros-fuerte-somepackage` because your system does not know where to find a repository containing these packages. To my knowledge, nobody publicly claimed that such a repository was available and chances are that you will not find one.

However, as Marco said, if you don't specifically need Fuerte, you can install ROS Groovy on Raspbian, there is a repository made just for that. I would recommend you follow the instructions on http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Raspbian. These instructions are not complete though, for the rest of the procedure you should rely on the generic Ubuntu install as can be found here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu, starting from item **1.5 Initialize rosdep**, and then on the different tutorials available for ROS Groovy.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) with karma: 411 on 2013-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlphaSierra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4924/alphasierra/) on 2013-06-13**:
Sounds like a plan, I'll try working through those. I'm still new to ROS, and just went with fuerte because that's what the tutorial covered.I had to build ROS from source while following those instructions, are those tools not included in those source repositories?

**Comment by [AlphaSierra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4924/alphasierra/) on 2013-06-14**:
So I got stuff to download, so that's that issue solved. Although the pcl is missing from following the instructions to install from source.

**Comment by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) on 2013-06-14**:
Have you tried `apt-get install ros-groovy-pcl`?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't need Fuerte and might be okay with Groovy, there is another tutorial for installing ROS on Raspbian which links from the Download->Raspbian. http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Raspbian

There is also a link on this page that points to a Source installation, as not all the packages are currently made available in the Raspbian ROS repository.

I particularly find this existence of two different Raspberry Pi installation tutorials disorienting.

---

Originally posted by [Marco Poli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4357/marco-poli/) with karma: 86 on 2013-06-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3